# Где найти интересные упражнения для Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby

Доброго времени суток.

Изучаю Ruby 1.9 по книге "Язык программирования Ruby" за авторством Флэнагана и Мацумото. Так вот, меня интересуют упражнения по примеру тех что были в "Язык программирования C" Кернигана и Ритчи, но ориентированные под специфику Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.codecademy.com/ru/tracks/ruby
- http://www.codeschool.com/paths/ruby

Comment: Интересно, спасибо.

Comment: Задачки там настолько простые, что с ними бы справилась и моя бабушка, которая тоже когда-то программировала. Правда, на перфокартах))

Comment: А чем программирование на перфокартах отличается от программирования на игральных картах? Я-то думал, что в эпоху перфокарт программировали на каких-то языках, ну, как минимум, машинные коды, а тут, оказывается на них ещё и программировать можно

Answer (score 0):

[Rubykoans](http://www.rubykoans.com/)

[Rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/)

[Rubytapas](http://www.rubytapas.com/episodes)